# Индексация сайта на vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте. Вопрос, возможно, глупый, но меня, как новичка, это очень интересует.
Предположим, я использую vuejs для интернет магазина. Товар выводится с помощью JS, фильтрация идет с помощью vue. Я так понимаю, что тогда будет проблема с индексацией сайта. Так как робот не сможет нормально проиндексировать то, что появляется после загрузки страницы.
Как в таком случае быть? Может я неправильно понимаю логику применения vue и подобных framework?

Comment: Правильно, индексация поисковиками невозможна в принципе :) Не знаю, чё там конкретно с Vue, но вот React иногда пихают в сервер и рисуют странички на нём специально для поисковика

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Современные поисковые движки хорошо заточены под индексирование более менее-статического контента. Поэтому с индексированием Single Page Applications, которые вообще целиком  js-динамика у них трудности. И это проблема. Как для поисковиков так и для разработчиков.

Со стороны разработчиков самым распространенным подходом является так называемый SSR - server side rendering. Это когда каркас приложения (значительная часть html-разметки) генерируется на сервере, потом отдается на клиент, соответственно поисковик может ее нормально проиндексировать. И на клиенте этот каркас обычно "оживляется" всякими дополнительными обработчиками и прочей динамикой в зависимости от действий юзера.

При этом кусочек серверной части приложения ответственной за рендеринг написан с использованием обычно примерно того же что и клиентской части. React там или vuejs. Поддержка SSR есть в большинстве современных js-фреймворков.

Конкретно у vue.js есть [**мануал  на русском языке про SSR.**](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/) Там много написано про SSR в общем, не только конкретно про vue.

Если вопросы SEO стоят прям очень жестко, то нужно учесть что поисковики пытаются решить проблему со своей стороны все лучше обучая своих ботов понимать динамику, и могут занижать в выдаче сайты с SSR.

[Но где-то год назад на родные механизмы полагаться было сложно и SSR был гораздо лучшим способом чем тонкая настройка под краулеры](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301288/).

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ!

Comment: Google хорошо индексирует чистые SPA, недавно проверял. Yandex не умеет.

Comment: Утка Учится Укрываться, а почему поисковики могут занижать в выдаче сайты с SSR? Если как раз в случае такого "каркаса" поисковик может страницу нормально проиндексировать

Comment: @Утка Учится Укрываться, добрый день, у меня аналогичный вопрос. А если vue будет генерировать контент в момент загрузки страницы, exemple.com?id=12, где при открытии страницы 12 из сервера будет прилетать json, а vue будет из него генерировать контент?

Comment: до сих пор все печально,сидим два сайта перелопачиваем))) два заказчика поддались уговорам фанатов трендо-новизны и заказали на VUE. В поисковиках только скелеты страниц . Кол-во страниц в индексе планомерно падает... По мнению ПС, они не полезны для людей.